# ASP.NET MVC 5 / EF 6 : "No connection string named could be found in the application config file." when adding migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I have a solution with two ASP.NET MVC web apps, each having its own connection string. Problem is only with one of these projects which has command interceptor. When I try to add migration to the project, I get this error if it is not set as startup project:

[image]

And this one if it is set as startup project:

[image]

Both errors occur at line 17 of the `KFI_IPPContext.vb` file:

[image]

When I comment out line 17, migration is added successfully. I have tried copying connection string to other 3 web.config files in my projects (1 in current, 2 in other project) with no luck. Cleaning and rebuilding solution doesn't work either. I know that I can comment / uncomment line for each migration without making any problem in my app, but my question is WHY?!